# In yaml-cpp is it possible to get the top-level key name in a document

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

Given the following sample.yaml file:

```
Foo:
  id: 10
  name: "bob"
```

Using yaml-cpp, how can one get the key name 'Foo'?

Given the code:

```
YAML::Node doc = YAML::LoadFile("sample.yaml");
cout << "doc.Type(): " << doc.Type() << "\n";
cout << "doc.size(): " << doc.size() << "\n";
cout << "doc[Foo][id]: " << doc["Foo"]["id"] << "\n";
```

Type() is 4 (Map) as expected (Foo is a Map).

size() is 1 as expected (Foo is the only item in doc).

doc[Foo][id] is 10 as expected.

But I cannot seem to figure out how to find "Foo" from the document's one node.  Iterating over doc produces a single Node but which throws exceptions for most of its operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (const auto& kv : doc) {
  std::cout << kv.first.as<std::string>() << "\n"; // prints Foo
  const YAML::Node& value = kv.second;  // the value
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the start. This works in 0.5, but in the latest, 0.6, things have changed. Now, to get the key name, it's just: std::cout << kv.first << "\n";

Adding ".as<std::string>()" is necessary to get it as a string, but it will stream to ostream automatically.

Comment: @DavyDurham That's true, both will work (I believe in both versions).